# Is it possible to make meta-phenol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Normally phenols have the $\ce{OH}$ group at the 1 or 4 position. Can they be made at 2 or 3 positions, where nitro groups and $\ce{-CN}$ can attach? If not, why not?

Comment: The enumeration of the phenyl carbons is arbitrarily chosen to start at the functional group. If you are not talking about isotopically labeling a phenol molecule, then the enumeration will not change.

Comment: I guess by "meta-phenol" you mean a phenol that has another group besides the $\ce{OH}$ group attached in the meta position of the aromatic ring, right?

Comment: Are you interested in Gallic Acid? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallic_acid

Comment: Related: [Why does m-cresol exist, given that -OH group is activating and should be o-, p-directing?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14889/7951)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hydroxyl groups in phenols are *ortho*-/*para*-directing. So, if you want to introduce a group in the *meta* position with respect to a hydroxyl group you will have to "overwrite" the *ortho*-/*para*-preference. This can be done by starting out with *meta*-directing group which can later be transformed into $\ce{OH}$ in the position where the hydroxyl group shall be. Then you only need to introduce the group you want to be in the *meta*-position by a simple electrophilic aromatic substitution reaction and subsequently convert the *meta*-directing group into $\ce{OH}$.

An example for this procedure would be to start out with a carbonyl group at the position of the $\ce{OH}$ group, then nitrate the aromatic ring in the *meta* position and employ the Baeyer-Villiger oxidation to introduce a $\ce{OH}$ group:

[image]

Or you start out with a nitro group at the position of the $\ce{OH}$ group, then introduce chlorine in the *meta* position of the aromatic ring, reduce the nitro group to an amine, which is then coverted into an diazonium salt which in turn is then transformed into a $\ce{OH}$ group using a Schiemann-type reaction:

[image]